# How to Use text in Arabic in Iphone App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, arabic

I want To Know that how we can use text as arabic in iphone applications and how we can create code . And also how we can show text in arabic on uilabel or uitextview.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Arabic Text in Label in XCode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375163/arabic-text-in-label-in-xcode)

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible to write

```
yourLabel.text = @"إعدادات"; // "Settings"
```

iOS supports arabic language since 3.0.

You'll have to manage text alignments yourself if you want to display right-to-left text.

Comment: Hi, I'm developing on iOS 4.2 and I'm developing arabic app. I wanted to search arabic text displayed on tableview using UISearchDisplayController the search is working correct with english text but it does not work with arabic. Any idea why this is happening? Thanks for (NSString *sTemp in searchArray)
 {
  NSRange titleResultsRange = [sTemp rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
  
  if (titleResultsRange.length > 0)
   [copyListOfItems addObject:sTemp];
 }

Comment: @Sarah Could you give an example of `searchText` and `searchArray` which leads to failure? I've just tried to search for a substring in an arabic string and it worked as expected.